# Storing text on GAE, non-standard unicode characters being changed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest

I have a servlet on Google App Engine that takes text from the page, stores it as an entity, and later sends it back to the client. When I store the word "You're", I get it showing up in the GAE localstore as "You're" as normal. When I return it to the client, however, I get "Youâre" and the debug code at times reads "Youâ??re". I am using the Java Text class to store this text.

How can I ensure that any Unicode characters can be stored correctly? It looks like client -> server is fine by the fact that the text does not change, but server -> client is definitely screwing up. Thanks!

Comment: Well I haven't even looked at GAE, but if it shows up fine in the GAE store but not to the users, could you be doing something with that text data to change it before sending it to the client?

Comment: maybe the problem is taht character encoding in your app and your browser are different, check if both are equal

Comment: I've got my meta-tag set to utf-8, so it should be displaying Unicode correctly on the client. I assume the same is on the server since it is showing up correctly there.

Comment: jetty uses ISO-8859-1 as default. try setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") on response and request

Comment: Found the problem. Oddly enough, removing the `setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` line that was already there made the whole thing work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of times I've seen this problem, either the page doesn't declare that it's using UTF-8, via something like

> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

or `accept-charset` isn't set in the form.

Could either of those be the case here?

Comment: I'm using backbone to send my models to the server, so basically it's just being sent with collection.create(). It ends up just sending itself to the server as a JSON object, so I'm not sure about any accept-charset. 

I have the meta tag in there though, and that isn't changing anything oddly enough. The console logs on the client also don't like the characters either. Perhaps they're being sent strangely from server to client?

Comment: If the console logs aren't happy, I'd look closely at the path that's delivering the data to the server initially.